# The retrained Inception v3 model is slow on Android

Tags: android, performance, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have retrained Inception v3 with my images of 68-classes and followed the tutorial in [Pete Warden's blog](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/) and [#1269](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1269) to make models available to the Android. I found that the retrained model is much slower than the default model.

In order to evaluate how each operation shown in [pages](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/) affects the model, I made a performance evaluation compared with 4 kinds of models, which all ran on the same device. The performance evaluation are listed as below:

Model (Operation)        ||  Recognition Time ||  Comments

---

1. default model          ||    400 ~ 450 ms || the default model-1000 classes, fastest
2. [strip_unused](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1269)           ||   2150 ~ 2500 ms || the retrained model removing the DecodeJpeg node, much slower than the default model
3. optimize_for_inference ||   1800 ~ 1950 ms || the retrained model optimized by the method in the [blog](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/), a little faster than model_2, but still very slow compared to the default model
4. 3 + quantize_graph     ||   1850 ~ 2000 ms || similar to model_3, not helpful for performance

The problem is what I should do to the model to make my retrained model as fast as the default model? The way I retrained the model is from the [tutorial of Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_retraining). Is there any trick I missed ? Please help, thanks!

Comment: I ran into similar issues and asked the devs about this. [Their response on github can be found here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10163) TLDR: The default model isn't the same one that you retrain so performance is different.

Comment: From this [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android), TF Classify is using Inception v1. So is there any one know how to retrain the model of inception v1 ?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I think you'd have to start that from scratch. Or perhaps someone else has started it. Not sure Sorry